# jQuery string appearing in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am seeing a sporadic issue that is causing me a headache to investigate.

I have a PHP page with a basic form with a few simple text fields.

jQuery is used to send this POST data back to the server which in turn saves a record in MySQL and sends email notifications. This works fine throughout the day but randomly (I cannot recreate it). the server will add the same record 5-10 times in the DB and send the same amount of emails.

The only clue to me which is causing this is that random a random jQuery string is included in some of the returned data (see below)

> Comments: Please can you sendjQuery17209552029577380006_1461157696021
>   this to me.

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 which explains the jQuery172, but not sure what the rest of this is.

Any ideas on where I should go with this? I may upgrade jQuery to see if this resolves it but thought I would ask here also?

***jQuery 1.7.2 Code Below:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#quick_form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl+'products/send_quote',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: 'prod_id='+$('input[name="prod_id"]').val() + '&' +
            'quote_name='+$('input[name="quote_name"]').val() + '&' +
            'quote_email='+$('input[name="quote_email"]').val() + '&' +
            'quote_phone='+$('input[name="quote_phone"]').val() + '&' +
            'quote_company='+$('input[name="quote_company"]').val() + '&' +
            'quote_cols='+$('input[name="quote_cols"]').val() + '&' +
            'quote_size='+$('input[name="quote_size"]').val() + '&' +
            'quote_qty='+$('input[name="quote_qty"]').val() + '&' +
            'quote_comments='+$('#quote_comments').val() + '&' +
            'token='+$('input[name="token"]').val(),
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response.success) {
                    $('#quote').slideUp('fast',function() { 
                    $('#quote').empty().html('<div class="successMessage">'+response.message+'</div>');
                    }).slideDown('fast');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.errMess').empty();
                        $.each(response.messages,function(k,v) {
                        $('.errMess').append('<div>'+v+'</div>').show();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: We can't do much here without seeing relevant code and db schema.

Comment: Looks like a generated callback function name

Comment: Have added the jquery which handles the submit. My thoughts are that its due to the old version of jQuery being used.

Comment: Yep. Mplungjan is right. That looks like a jsonp callback function name.

Comment: Thanks, sorry to sound dumb here, but any ideas why this might be happening (where I could look) iv'e not used jQuery much. Hence the dumb question..

Comment: look in the console (F12) press network, click the return from your server and see the content likely has some garbage in it you did not expect. If the datatype:"json" is correct, then you want to extract the right data from the response